# SSD temps via Libre Hardware monitor

Tags: hardware, monitor, openhardwaremonitor

This code brings average CPU temps via powershell script
but can't find callouts to SSD or HDD temps
how can i find callout documentations?

```
   
cls
$dll = "LibreHardwareMonitorLib.dll"

Unblock-File -LiteralPath $dll
Add-Type -LiteralPath $dll
$monitor = [LibreHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Computer]::new()
$monitor.IsCPUEnabled = $true

$monitor.Open()
[int]$temp = foreach ($sensor in $monitor.Hardware.Sensors) {
    if ($sensor.SensorType -eq 'Temperature' -and $sensor.Name -eq 'Core Average'){
        $sensor.Value
        break
    }
}
$monitor.Close()
write-host "$temp"
```

reason im using Libre cos its only option to make scripts via cli, if u know other hardware monitor api's that can work with powershell i would appriciate it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the [LibreHardwareMonitor GitHub documentation](https://github.com/LibreHardwareMonitor/LibreHardwareMonitor), you are missing the Storage initiators.

Not familiar with your code but should look similar to this:

```
cls
$dll = "LibreHardwareMonitorLib.dll"

Unblock-File -LiteralPath $dll
Add-Type -LiteralPath $dll
$monitor = [LibreHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Computer]::new()
$monitor.IsCPUEnabled = $true
$monitor.IsStorageEnabled = $true

$monitor.Open()
[int]$temp = foreach ($sensor in $monitor.Hardware.Sensors) {
    if ($sensor.SensorType -eq 'Temperature' -and $sensor.Name -eq 'Core Average'){
        $sensor.Value
        break
    }
}
[int]$temp2 = foreach ($sensor in $monitor.Hardware.Sensors) {
    if ($sensor.SensorType -eq 'Temperature' -and $sensor.Name -eq 'Temperature'){
        $sensor.Value
        break
    }
}
$monitor.Close()
write-host "$temp"
write-host "$temp2"
```

Make sure to optimize the code, I have just added another loop for the SSD but just reworking the first one would be better. Also, SensorType and Name for the SSD may be different, I just used those because that is what i see in my Python app using LibreHardwareMonitor.dll.

```
Temperature   /nvme/0/temperature/0   45.0
Available Spare   /nvme/0/level/1   100.0
Available Spare Threshold   /nvme/0/level/2   5.0
Percentage Used   /nvme/0/level/3   0.0
Data Read   /nvme/0/data/4   1423.0
Data Written   /nvme/0/data/5   1380.0
Used Space   /nvme/0/load/0   36.56363296508789
Read Activity   /nvme/0/load/31   0.0
Write Activity   /nvme/0/load/32   1.2101701498031616
Total Activity   /nvme/0/load/33   1.3301831483840942
Read Rate   /nvme/0/throughput/34   0.0
Write Rate   /nvme/0/throughput/35   109381.328125
```